# Database Login failed in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

In my application I have created a report in html view.

For that I have used view model to load the data.

Now to convert it to the pdf and save the file I wanted to create a crystal report using the same view model.

So I created new crystal report.

Then I choose my view data models from the .net project list

For this there are two view models I'm using. and then I created the report.

To check this method working, Within the html view generated controller I have done these code.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
   AppRequest appRequest = db.AppRequest.Find(id);
   if (appRequest.General.Count != 0)
   {
    List<ReportViewModel>RequestView = new List<ReportViewModel>();
    var ReqDetails = (from a in db.AppRequest
                      join e in db.CreateEmployee on a.Req_By equals e.Id
                      join c in db.CreateCompany on e.CompanyId equals c.Id
                      join d in db.CreateDesignation on e.DesignId equals d.Id
                      join dep in db.CreateDepartment on e.DepId equals dep.Id
                      join g in db.General on a.Id equals g.Req_Id
                      where a.Id == id
                      select new ReportViewModel
                      {
                        RequestedDate = a.Req_Date.ToString(),
                        RequestBy = e.EmpName,
                        CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                        RequestByDessignation = d.Designation,
                        RequestByDepartment = dep.Department,
                        ApprovalId = g.ApprovedNumber,
                        CoverNote = a.Req_CoverNote,
                        GeneralItemsApprovedList = (from a in db.AppRequest
                                                    join g in db.General on a.Id equals g.Req_Id
                                                    join gi in db.GeneralItms on g.Id equals gi.General_Id
                                                    where a.Id == id && gi.IsApproved == true
                                                    select new GeneralItemsApprovedList
                                                    {
                                                     ItemDescription = gi.Attachment_Description,
                                                     ItemPrice = gi.Attachment_Amount.ToString(),
                                                     GenId = gi.Id
                                                    }).ToList(),
    ApprovalList = (from a in db.AppRequest
                    join ap in db.ApprovalProcess on a.Id equals ap.Req_Id
                    join pa in db.ApproveParties on ap.Id equals pa.ApprovalProcess_Id
                    join ae in db.CreateEmployee on pa.Approver_Id equals ae.Id
                    join ad in db.CreateDesignation on ae.DesignId equals ad.Id
                    where a.Id == id
                    select new ApprovalList
                    {
                     ApproveDate = pa.Approved_Date.ToString(),
                     ApprovedBy = ae.EmpName,
                     ApprovedByDessignation = ad.Designation,
                    }).ToList()
             }).ToList();
   return View("ApprovedReport", ReqDetails);
}
```

And this is the code I wrote for the crystal report after this main code.

```
CrystalReports.cryGeneralRequest rpt = new CrystalReports.cryGeneralRequest();
rpt.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReports"), "cryGeneralRequest.rpt"));
rpt.SetDataSource(ReqDetails);
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
try
{
 Stream steam = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
 steam.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
 return File(steam, "application/pdf", "General.pdf");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw;
}
```

Error in the Stream line says that database login error. How to fix this ?

P.S - Updating 13/12/2021

In the code I have again changed as this

```
CrystalReports.cryGeneralRequest rpt = new CrystalReports.cryGeneralRequest();
                rpt.SetDataSource(ReqDetails);
                rpt.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReports"), "cryGeneralRequest.rpt"));
                ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "db_a7cea6_pasweb";
                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                rpt.Load();

                try
                {
                    Stream steam = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                    steam.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return File(steam, "application/pdf", "General.pdf");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw;
                }
```

But still the same error. Also, I need to inform you that in the same Controller I have mentioned my DB connection as this `private zSqlDb db = new zSqlDb();` and then the query and passing that to ViewModel is running. So `ReqDetails` part is already containing the data and I'm assigning to the report datasource as the same. So is there any wrong with that part ?

Comment: Where have you placed the database credentials in crystal report code?

Comment: add connection statically in crystal report. @Yrox Mk

Comment: @AvanthaSiriwardana Machan I have put my db connection on a model and in this controller upper area I have called to the db connection. Do I need to include again within the crystal report code also ?

Comment: I would recommend to configure the credentials in crystal report machan.

Comment: @zambee Can you give me an example for that ?

Comment: @zambee  I have updated the issue.

Comment: @AvanthaSiriwardana I have updated the issue

Comment: @YroxMk something like this; rpt.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", "server", "database"); Sample - https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/crystal-reports-sample-in-aspnet.html